# How to Verify Paypal Pro Signature in PHP?

Tags: paypal

I m working on a Web App and using Paypal Pro.
 I need to Verify if owner/admin have added valid Username, Password and API Signature in the configuration Settings so that owner/admin cannot put invalid credentials.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Make an API call.  If it works, the credentials are valid.  GetBalance is a good one to test with.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewAngell i got the Solution.